# Is every written syllable pronounced?

Tags: pronunciation

So, I'm looking at some songs and it seems that all of the syllables are actually pronounced in every word, are there no silent syllables in Italian? or is it just the singers being extra careful?

For instance, when you read [*Con te partirò*](https://dailyitalianwords.com/con-te-partiro-andrea-bocelli-lyrics-english-translation/), it seems he sings every single sound.

Or when Laura Pausini sings [*La solitudine*](http://www.saberitaliano.com.ar/songs/12.html), the only  word that seems missing  is the one in bold in the following sentence:

> Ma **il** cuore batte forte dentro me.

Comment: Why shouldn't they be pronounced?

Comment: Credo che intenda che alcune lettere, più che sillabe, non sono pronunciate, come avviene in altre lingue

Comment: @BakerStreet D'accordo, ma in ogni caso è una domanda che rasenta l'insensatezza. È un po' come chiedere se i meli facciano mele e se sì perché. Stanno particolarmente attenti?

Comment: Non è che ho capito tanto bene che intendi. Volevo dire che la domanda chiede se in italiano si pronunciano tutte le lettere che sono scritte, a differenza di altre lingue in cui alcune lettere non si pronunciano: ad esempio in francese *vous* si legge *vù*, la *s* non si pronuncia, *beaucoup* si legge *bocù*, la *p* non si pronuncia.

Comment: Sì, grazie. A parte che l'OP dice “sillabe” e fino a prova contraria intende quello, in ogni caso non capisco come si possa rispondere a una domanda del genere. Al limite, è strano che una lettera o una sillaba si scriva ma _non_ si pronunci, e se ne potrebbe cercare una spiegazione. Che si scriva e si pronunci mi sembra un po' il default. Ma forse è un limite mio.

Comment: @BakerStreet: I tried to give an answer. I hope I understood what OP meant.

Comment: Of course, I agree that the question is not very clear. Well, in French having letters  that one doesn't pronounce, or also that are pronounced in some context and not pronounced in others context,  is the rule, it a difficulty of reading French.

Comment: @DaG  the few languages I'm familiar with have a good quantity of words with silent syllables,  Like Queue and Half in english or Recepção  and Terceiro in Portugal and Brazil respectivelly

Comment: @JonathanDS: I'm not sure we mean the same thing by “syllable”. Where would the silent syllable be in “half”? I follow the dictionary definition of “a unit of pronunciation having one vowel sound, with or without surrounding consonants, forming the whole or a part of a word; for example, there are two syllables in _water_ and three in _inferno_”.

Comment: @DaG i think you nailed it

Answer (score 7):

Yes, in Italian every single syllable is normally pronounced. The possible exceptions you might have in mind are:

In a brisk conversation, a speaker *might* be imprecise in their enunciation and, say, chop some fragment of some word. So a question like *Che ore sono?* (What time is it?) might sound something like “Ch'ore sono?”, but this is definitely not the standard pronunciation.

In a different context, when reading aloud a poem so as to have its lines scan exactly (and something analogous happens with songs too), in Italian as in other languages there are phenomenons such as [synalepha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synalepha), in which consecutive vowels belonging to different syllables “merge” resulting, phonetically, in a single syllable. For instance, the second line of Dante's *Inferno* reads

> mi ritrovai per una selva oscura [I found myself in a dark wood].

Here *selva oscura*, which is composed of five syllables (sel-va-o-scu-ra) and normally read as such, will be read as composed by just four, pronouncing “vao” as a single syllable (which in a careless enunciation might almost sound as “vo”). This is what the poet wanted, as proved by the fact that the whole line is a hendecasyllable (mi-ri-tro-vai-per-u-na-sel-vao-scu-ra).
In normal speech, on the other hand, there is no reason not to say “selva oscura” with all of its five syllables. So, if anything, singers are careful to merge some syllables where necessary for rhythm.

Comment: I would argue that the synalepha is the standard pronunciation while not attempting to enunciate clearly (I certainly do it often in normal speech), since not doing so requires introducing an extraneous silence between two sounds (selva [pause] oscura) instead of easily pronouncing them with the same breath outflow. Either way, I agree with your general point.

Comment: "selva'oscura" , Italian is so beautiful